# How to drop columns with little to no values?

Tags: python, pandas, database, data-analysis

I have a survey data set where there are columns with little to no response available. I wanted to drop those columns. How do I do that? The image is an example of part of my data set. The red highlighted are columns I would want to drop.

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJlH3.png)

Ive tried using the dropna() method but it only remnoved 2/612 columns which doesnt seem right.

```
#identify and remove missing data
df = df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
print(df)
```

There should be at least 25 percent of columns that should be dropped. Im not sure what specific parameters I need to place to get that.

Comment: Are those actually NaN values, or are they blank strings?  Have you tried using `thresh` instead of `how='all'`?

Comment: If you use `print(df.isna().sum(axis=1))` it will show the number of columns  in each row which really have None/NaN elements.

Comment: I've used thresh but it still not giving me anywhere near the right amount of columns. And yea I think it changed to NaN on its own. Should I do something different since its a NaN?